# Is it possible to get some portion of the ElasticSearch request data in the response unchanged?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a need to pass some data to the ElasticSearch request and have it translated to the response as is, or with minimal structural differences.

For example, a request might look like this:

```
GET myindex/_search?metadata=12345
{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [...], 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my-type": "typename"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like the response to include this `metadata=12345` unchanged, for instance:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [...]
  },
  "metadata" : "12345"
}
```

Is there a way to tell ElasticSearch not to parse some data in the original request, but translate it to the response "as is"?

I know this sounds like an absurd requirement, so here's some background. The ES request is constructed in one place of code, and the response is analyzed in another. Mixing that would require some significant refactoring, which is better to be avoided. Hence, if I could get a part of my original request back in the response unchanged, that would be a quick win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, I don't think there's such a thing in the `Elasticsearch` response, because it's fixed response template and can't be customized (correct me if I'm wrong).

But here's an alternative; in the `Elasticsearch` aggregations, there's [metadata type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/agg-metadata.html) that would help you in a case like this, for instance:

Let's assume this is your request:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [...], 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my-type": "typename"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "metadata": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": ""
      },
      "meta": {
        "value": "12345"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, you'll get the response that contains the unchanged metadata, but in another format, something like:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [...]
  },
  ,
  "aggregations": {
    "metadata": {
      "meta": {
        "value": "12345"
      },
      "value": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds interesting. Do you know if this kind of aggregations add any time to the request execution?

Comment: Do you mean when elasticsearch add this aggregation?

Comment: Yep, I mean is it heavier for ES to execute compared to the one without aggregations? Doesn't look like that, but maybe there are hidden surprises... :)

Comment: It's a metadata aggregation with no field value count, so I don't think it's a big deal in addition to there's no alternative as I know :)

Comment: Brilliant! I think I'll go with this solution! Thanks a lot for your help!